# Login page is skipped in Lotus Notes

Tags: authentication, settings, lotus-notes

I work in a web based application in Lotus Notes. Suddenly, the login page is skipped and it is directly going to functionality. What may be the reason? Is it a settings issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible reasons:

- You have granted the "Anonymous" user access to the application.
  Verify the ACL of the database.
- You have some sort of SSO solution in
  your company that logs you in automatically. (LTPA token on the IBM
  WebSphere plugin for IIS, for example).

I assume you are testing your application on an actual Domino server, and are not using the "preview" function of Domino Designer.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen...now I am facing a new issue. I am getting the login page, but the logout button is not working..What may be the reason?

Comment: What's the url the logut-button points to? it should point to something like this: http://server/database.nsf?logout&redirectto=http://server/database.nsf. Also make sure you have session-based authentication enabled on the server. Not basic authentication.